# Calculating a determinant in Lua

Tags: math, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to calculate determinants with any order using Lua. I can calculate determinants for order less than 4, but not for greater equals than 4 ones.
I have a 4x4 matrix and its determinant with the program is 0, but the real solution is 56.
I don't know if the problem is in **getSubmatrix** method or is in **detMat** method, because I don't have any error message from the console.
I've ported the methods from my own java code, where it works fine.
Here's all my code:

```
function numMat(n, A)
    local S = {}
    for i = 1, #A, 1 do
        local T = {}
        S[i] = T
        for j =1, #A[1], 1 do
            T[j] = n * A[i][j]
        end
    end
    return S
end

function sumMat(A, B)
    local C = {}
    for i = 1, #A do
        local D = {}
        C[i] = D
        for j = 1, #A[1] do
            D[j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j]
        end
    end
    return C
end

function subMat(A, B)
    return sumMat(A, numMat(-1, B))
end

function printMatrix(A)
    for i, v in ipairs(A) do
        for j, w in ipairs(v) do
            print(w)
        end
    end
end

function escalarProduct(u, v)
    local w = 0
    for i = 1, #u do
        w = w + u[i] * v[i]
    end
    return w
end

function prodMat(A, B)
    local C = {}
    for i = 1, #A do
        C[i] = {}
        for j = 1, #B[1] do
            local num = A[i][1] * B[1][j]
            for k = 2, #A[1] do
                num = num + A[i][k] * B[k][j]
            end
            C[i][j] = num
        end
    end
    return C
end

function powMat(A, power)
    local B = {}
    local C = {}
    C = A
    for i = 1, power - 1 do
        B = prodMat(C, A)
        C = B
    end
    return B
end

function trasposeMat(A)
    local B = {}
    for i = 1, #A do
        local C = {}
        B[i] = C
        for j = 1, #A[1] do
            C[j] = A[j][i]
        end
    end
    return B
end

function productDiag(m)
    local prod = 1
    for i = 1, #m do
        for j = 1, #m do
            if i == j then prod = prod * m[i][i] end
        end
    end
    return prod
end

function isDiagonal(A)
    for i = 1, #A do
        for j = 1, #A do
            if i ~= j and A[i][j] ~= 0 then return false end
        end
    end
    return true
end

function isTriangSup(m)
    for i = 1, #m do
        for j = 1, i do
            if m[i][j] == 0 then return true end
        end
    end
    return false
end

function isTriangInf(m)
    return isTriangSup(trasposeMat(m))
end

function isTriang(m)
    if(isTriangSup(m)) then return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function getSubmatrix(A, rows, cols, col)
    local submatrix = {}
    local k = 1

    for j = 1, cols do
        --local D = {}
        --submatrix[j] = D
        if j == col then
            break
        end
        for i = 2, rows do
            submatrix[i-1][k] = A[i][j]
            --D[k] = A[i][j]
        end
        k = k + 1
    end
    return submatrix
end

function det2Mat(A)
    assert(#A == 2 and #A == #A[1], 'Error: The matrix must be squared, order 2.')
    return A[1][1] * A[2][2] - A[1][2] * A[2][1]
end

function det3Mat(A)
    assert(#A == 3 and #A == #A[1], 'Error: The matrix must be squared, order 3.')
    s1 = A[1][1] * A[2][2] * A[3][3] + A[2][1] * A[3][2] * A[1][3] + A[1][2] * A[2][3] * A[3][1]
    s2 = A[1][3] * A[2][2] * A[3][1] + A[1][2] * A[2][1] * A[3][3] + A[2][3] * A[3][2] * A[1][1]
    return s1 - s2
end

function detMat(A)
    local submatrix = {}
    local det
    local sign = 1
    local rows = #A
    local cols = #A[1]

    assert(rows == cols, 'Error: The matrix must be squared.')
    if rows == 1 then
        return A[1][1]
    end
    if rows == 2 then
        return det2Mat(A)
    end
    if rows == 3 then
        return det3Mat(A)
    end

    if isDiagonal(A) or isTriang(A) then return productDiag(A) end
    if rows > 3 then
        for column = 1, cols do
            submatrix = getSubmatrix(A, rows, cols, column)
            det = det + sign * A[1][column] * detMat(submatrix)
            sign = -sign
        end
    end
    return det
end

A = {{1, 3}, {5, 6}}
B = {{2, 4}, {3, 1}}
C = {{2, 3, 4}, {-5, 4, 7}, {7, 1, 0}}
D = {{2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 7, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 6}}
E = {{2, 3, 4, -3}, {-5, 4, 7, -2}, {7, 1, 0, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6}}

--printMatrix(numMat(-1, A))
--printMatrix(sumMat(A, B))
--printMatrix(subMat(A, B))
--print(escalarProduct({1, 3}, {5, 6}))
--printMatrix(prodMat(A, B))
--printMatrix(trasposeMat(A))
--printMatrix(powMat(A, 2))
--printMatrix(powMat(A, 3))

print(detMat(A))
print(detMat(B))
print(detMat(C))
print(detMat(D))
print(detMat(E)) --The solution must be 56
```

And the console solution is:

**-9
-10
1
336
0**

The error is when I want to find out the determinant of the matrix E.

Comment: The logical error is in `getSubmatrix()` in the line `if j == col then break end`  Operator "break" exists the outer  loop.  Instead, you should skip inner loop (i.e, use operator "continue").  But unfortunately, there is no "continue" in Lua, so you should use `if j ~= col then ...(inner loop here)... k=k+1 end`

Comment: BTW, functions `isTriangSup` and `isTriangInf` are wrong